# JSmooth Java 1.4 or above not found error

Tags: java, jar, exe, jsmooth

I have installed JSmooth. My computer has JDK 1.7 & JRE 1.7. but it says need java 1.4 or above to open & try to download. Why is that ??

Comment: You've probably installed Java 7 in a place that JSmooth can't find, or something like that

Comment: Java installed in program files with the OS files. Why JSmooth can't find that?

Comment: OK! It needs JAVA_HOME environmental variable assigned. :)

Comment: JSmooth may need to be taught about Java 7.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your JDK or JRE base path, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91`. For this, go to Control Panel -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System Variables -> New.

I was initially confused by the same problem because `java` and `javac` were working on the command line so I thought all variables were set up but `JAVA_HOME` does not seem to be set by default when installing a JDK.

Answer (score 0):

From the JSmooth documentation

> Something goes wrong at launch-time, and the wrapper won't start my java application. How can I investigate?
>
> The first thing to do, is to run the wrapper with the additional argument -JskelDebug=1 (the option is case-sensitive). This will start the wrapper in debug mode, displaying a console (or using the current one, for the console wrapper), and output many useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I was also in the same problem for a whole night. I installed JVM again, JSmooth again, didn't happened any thing... Then I downloaded and installed [this](http://www.dmt.com/jvm_download.htm) and suddenly it recognized JVM. I guess, to access JVM, this app need Microsoft VM... a rough guess though!

Comment: @Konrad Höffner's answer is right, you just have to set JAVA_HOME variable, not need to install any thing else :)